# Add nested remote method with loopbackjs

Tags: loopbackjs

I'm using strongloop's loopbackjs at work to implement an API.

For a model `Cat` I have defined a remote method, lets call it `meow`.

So i can do:

`GET /cats/{:id}/meow`

The `Cat` model belongsTo the `User` model.

Now I would like to be able to do something like this:

`GET /users/{:id}/cats/{:id}/meow`

Does anyone know how to do this?

I already tried nestRemoting, which only works for nested 'blueprint' methods.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a remote method in the User Model and then use it to call the meow method of CatModel

```
UserModel.someRemoteMethod = function(id1,id2,cb){
     CatModel.meow(id2,cb);
 }


  UserModel.remoteMethod(
    'someRemoteMethod',
    {
      accepts: [
        {arg: 'id1', type: 'number', required: true},
        {arg: 'id2', type: 'number', required: true}
      ],
      http: {path: '/:id1/cats/:id2/meow', verb: 'get'}
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `nestRemoting('relationName')`. It's not well documented, but for your model you can use:

```
User.on('attached', function() {
   User.nestRemoting('catRelation');
}
```

Put this in your `user.js` file and you should get the endpoints you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution i need to share with all of you

nestRemoting function take an options json object which contain an attribute called filterMethod this method filter the model function to get only the defaults methods so i passed this attribute callback function with customization in the ( else if ) to check my remote method ( DoWhat ) and return it

```
server.models.Client.nestRemoting('units', {filterMethod: function(method, relation) {
        let regExp = /^__([^_]+)__([^_]+)$/;
        let matches = method.name.match(regExp);
        if (matches) {
            return '__' + matches[1] + '__' + relation.name + '__' + matches[2];
        } else if (method.name === 'DoWhat') {
            return method.name;
        }
    }});
```

I hope this solution help you